# Java Observable to throw error if it occurs

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

Is there a way to have an Observable just throw an exception that occurs from within a function like `flatMap()`?

In Java, on a normal function, you can specify that it may throw an exception:

```
public void dangerousFunction() throws IOException {}
```

Within an `Observable` function like `flatMap()`, I can't seem to find a similar syntax. I can use a `try/catch` like this:

```
myObservable.flatMap(() -> {
    try {
        return dangerousFunction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Observable.error(e);
    }
});
```

Is there a cleaner method for writing that? If I have lots of maps and/or `Observables`, that winds up being a lot of `try/catch` blocks cluttering up my code.

Comment: This article may help: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to dealing with exceptions in a RxJava `map()` method is propagate the exception by catch-and-throw. For example:

```
.map(b -> {
   try {
       ...
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       // manual catch and throw
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);

       // or catch-and-throw using a built-in helper
       throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
   }
})
```

This can be get quite verbose when repeated across multiple `map()` calls so you could define a helper to wrap this behaviour e.g.

```
observable.map(RxMapWrapper.wrapAndThrow(new RxMapWrapper.Func1Wrapper<A, B>() {
        @Override
        public B call(A document) throws Exception {
            // your map logic here ...
        }
    }))

public class RxMapWrapper {
    public static <T, R> Func1<T, R> wrapAndThrow(Func1Wrapper<T, R> caughtFunction) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                return caughtFunction.call(t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
            }
        };
    }

    public interface Func1Wrapper<T, R> extends Function {
        R call(T t) throws Exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return `Observable.error(e)` inside catch blocks, you don't need try/catch at all. Exception would go to downstream and `.subscribe(,throwable)` will catch it anyway.

If you want to return some other/default object when error occurred, try these operators: `onErrorReturnItem`, `onErrorResumeNext`, `onErrorReturn`. This would be cleaner.

Other option would be implementing this `onErrorReturnItem` mechanism into your methods itself instead of throwing Exception.